# QT vs Flex/Flash/AIR for multimedia

Tags: java, apache-flex, flash, qt, actionscript

I develop a MIDI application using AIR that read MIDI code from Java and found it could not perform fast enough unless I move everything to Java. In actionscript, does Green thread can improve AIR/Flash by acting as a multithread application which can improve NativeProcess performance in reading and writing?

If not, say would you suggest moving all to Java or choosing Qt framework? I am not comfortable with C++ language.

Comment: Hi, as is the case many times I don't have a direct answer to this question but I might be able to give you a bit more info to help. AIR/Flash itself is not multi-threaded the only way to fake multithreading is to block background processing to let the UI update then resume after some data processing is complete. If you truly need muli-threaded support I would suggest sticking with Java, and if you'd like to use the QT framework see the binding here: http://qt-jambi.org/

Comment: Also one more short note, if it isn't obvious you will get the best performance from writing it in C or C++ then compiling down to machine code for a particular processor rather than anything running on top of a virtual machine.  That being said if your careful about how you present data to AS from Java you can likely pull off the UI in AS you just need to load all the heavy preprocessing in Java (at some point the serialization of the objects will also become a choke point but updates every 1/30 of a second would keep the animation fluid and up to date and shouldn't overload the proc).

Answer (score 1):

The Flash player does not provide multithreading support. However, if you are writing a desktop application (using the AIR runtime) you can use a NativeProcess to spawn a commandline tool (python, java, ruby, C, etc etc) to do the Midi processing in the background leaving Flash to just handle the UI updates, which is what Flash is really all about.

Green threading can be a useful approach for some data processing tasks that slow down the framerate but I suspect that your MIDI processing is quite intensive - it probably does not belong in Flash.

If you are deploying to the web, then using a Java (or any other server-side resource) for MIDI processing is your best bet. You'd have to provide more detail on the type of processing if you want me to get more specific.